# Is data shared between worker processes in an IIS7 Application Pool

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

If I set the Maximum Worker Processes > 1 will my singleton objects be shared between the processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, .NET objects will not be shared between processes as each process gets its own address space. Also if you're using in-process caching of any kind (singleton objects is one kind of caching), including in-process session state, it can't be shared between the worker processes. Having multiple worker processes is similar to having multiple web servers with a load-balancer.